# Проверка на подписку VK API.[Python]

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток!
Есть часть кода:

```
if "ключ" in response['items'][0]['body']:
    write_msg(item['user_id'], ' | %Имя пользователя%, спасибо, что подписался! ')
```

- Каким образом с помощь API можно проверить подписан ли человек, или
  нет?
- Как можно вместо `%Имя пользователя%` подставить имя человека из
  профиля Vk, который написал.

Всё это в сообщениях сообщества, на python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот пример:

```
import vk
def Authorization():  # Авторизация пользователя
    return vk.API(vk.AuthSession(app_id='***',
                                user_login='***',
                                user_password='***',
                                scope='groups'))

def foo(session):
    if session.groups.isMember(group_id = 'Group id'): # Проверяем является ли пользователь участником сообщества
        return 'Вы уже подписаны.'
    session.groups.join(group_id = 'Group id')  # ID Группы. Подписываемся 
    return 'Спасибо за подписку {0}'.format(session.users.get()[0]['first_name'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(foo(Authorization()))
```

Для теста я создал пустую группу, вот результат если вы не являетесь подписчиком:

```
Спасибо за подписку Павел
```

[Документация](https://vk.com/dev/groups) по методам групп VK.